Manipulate arrays which have $var in their names
I am trying to manipulate associative arrays that contain $var in their names.
# this does not work
for i in {1..3}; do declare -A tab$i=( [nom]="john" [comment]="this does not work"); done

# this works, but requires eval when setting values
for i in {1..3}; do declare -A tab$i; done
tab$i[comment]="still wrong !"                 # doesn't work
eval tab$i[comment]="finally succeeded !!!"    # works

How can I declarate and initialize them without resorting to:

eval
writing to a temp file that I source later


It would be easier to put $i into the key. tab[comment$i]="xxx"

bash nameref
Playing with bash's Associative arrays and Nameref:
Regarding your approach
You could:
for i in {1..3}; do
    declare -A "tab$i=( [nom]='john' [comment]='this work fine.' [id]='$i')"
done

Then
declare  -p ${!tab*}

declare -A tab1=([nom]="john" [id]="1" [comment]="this work fine." )
declare -A tab2=([nom]="john" [id]="2" [comment]="this work fine." )
declare -A tab3=([nom]="john" [id]="3" [comment]="this work fine." )

Splitting definition and assignation
But my recommended way would look like:
for i in {1..3}; do
    declare -A "tab$i=()"
    declare -n thistab="tab$i"
    thistab['nom']='john' thistab['comment']='this work fine.' thistab['id']="$i"
done

declare  -p ${!tab*}

declare -A tab1=([nom]="john" [id]="1" [comment]="this work fine." )
declare -A tab2=([nom]="john" [id]="2" [comment]="this work fine." )
declare -A tab3=([nom]="john" [id]="3" [comment]="this work fine." )

Thinking about variable name
Or maybe:
for varname in tab{1..3}; do
    declare -A "$varname=()"
    declare -n thistab="$varname"
    thistab['id']="${varname//[^0-9]}"
    thistab['nom']='john' thistab['comment']='this work fine.'
done

Edit existing variable content
Then...
for i in {1..3}; do
    declare -n thistab="tab$i"
    thistab['2nd comment']="This will work too!"
    thistab['someRandom']=$(( RANDOM % 90 + 10 ))
done

Then
declare  -p ${!tab*}

declare -A tab1=([nom]="john" [id]="1" [someRandom]="14" ["2nd comment"]="This w
ill work too!" [comment]="this work fine." )
declare -A tab2=([nom]="john" [id]="2" [someRandom]="50" ["2nd comment"]="This w
ill work too!" [comment]="this work fine." )
declare -A tab3=([nom]="john" [id]="3" [someRandom]="38" ["2nd comment"]="This w
ill work too!" [comment]="this work fine." )

Note the space in key: 2nd comment.
Same, using existing variable name
for varname in "${!tab@}"; do
    declare -n thistab="$varname"
    thistab['2nd comment']="This will work too!"
    thistab['someRandom']=$(( RANDOM % 90 + 10 ))
    if [[ ${thistab['nom']} == john ]]; then
        thistab['nom']+=" doe"
    fi
done

declare  -p ${!tab*}

declare -A tab1=([nom]="john doe" [id]="1" [someRandom]="64" ["2nd comment"]="Th
is will work too!" [comment]="this work fine." )
declare -A tab2=([nom]="john doe" [id]="2" [someRandom]="73" ["2nd comment"]="Th
is will work too!" [comment]="this work fine." )
declare -A tab3=([nom]="john doe" [id]="3" [someRandom]="89" ["2nd comment"]="Th
is will work too!" [comment]="this work fine." )

